# Creating Multiple Birt Charts From the same series

Tags: birt

I have a chart in Birt. How can I make multiple charts from the same series. For example. I only want to display 10 x values, and if the x values are greater than 10 I want to make x/10 graphs. I would need to do this since, I don't want to clutter the chart with too many values.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

- Add a RUNNINGCOUNT Computed Column to your dataset.
- Add a Table to your report (bound to your dataset.
- Group your new table on the Ceiling of your RUNNINGCOUNT divided by 10.
- Add your graph to the group footer of your table.